# What are the drawbacks for the body of eating an apple?

Tags: diet, fruits

Most people would say that eating fruit is good for us; vitamins, micro-nutrients, phyto-chemicals.

However, a colleague of mine told me he eats no fruit because of the sugar.

Is eating an apple as bad as eating an equivalent amount of pure sugar with a spoon? (Assuming pure sugar is considered bad for us.)

Is there any other way in which eating a fruit is bad for us?

Comment: Voted to close. There is no quantifiable measure for "badness" or "goodness" of food.

Comment: If your question gets closed, please don't just open a new one on the same subject. Edit the previous question so the community can vote whether it is now on-topic.

Comment: I just thought, thing being a beta and all, that bad questions could stay and teach others what to ask and what not to ask.

Comment: He isn't asking for badness, He is asking for drawbacks to eating fruits caused by sugars. I could start with the effects of sugar on teeth.

Comment: Is it still not good enough?

Comment: This book http://www.adlibris.com/se/bok/fat-chance-9780007514144 suggests that the sugar in the apple is embedded in dietary fiber which protects me from the drawbacks of the sugar.